# Gridview of image from sdcard directory

Tags: android, gridview, android-sdcard

I want show image in gridview from sdcard directory.i use this code.But when i load image by type : bitmap.getView in gridview adapter need Integer[] array.how i can fix it?

```
public class LoadPic extends Activity {

Integer[] imageIDs = {
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user,
        R.drawable.user
};

int numberOfImages=0;
Bitmap[] m;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.load_pic);


    Intent gett = getIntent();


    String _area = gett.getStringExtra("area");
    String _domain = gett.getStringExtra("domain");
    String _block = gett.getStringExtra("block");
    String _melk = gett.getStringExtra("melk");
    String _build = gett.getStringExtra("build");
    String _apar = gett.getStringExtra("apar");
    String _senfi = gett.getStringExtra("senfi");




    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/momayezi/"+_area+"-"+_domain+"-"+_block+"-"+_melk+"-"+_build+"-"+_apar+"-"+_senfi);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    numberOfImages=files.length;


    for (int i=1;i<=numberOfImages;i++)
    {

        File img = new File("/sdcard/momayezi/"+_area+"-"+_domain+"-"+_block+"-"+_melk+"-"+_build+"-"+_apar+"-"+_senfi+"/pic"+i+".png");


        if(img.exists())
        {
            Bitmap bit = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(img.getAbsolutePath());

        }

    }




    GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View v, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "pic" + (position + 1) + " selected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



}



public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c)
    {
        context = c;
    }

    //---returns the number of images---
    public int getCount() {
        return numberOfImages;
    }

    //---returns the ID of an item---
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    //---returns an ImageView view---
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(185, 185));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(7, 7, 7, 7);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }


        /**/
        imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);
        /**/

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

}

please help how i can use image in this class(adapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show images from sdcard into your grid view use any imageloader library

**Universal Image Loader**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

then you need to create a string array or a model class instead of that integer array.
Please refer the below tutorials.

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/loading-thumbnail-images-in-a-gridview-and-opening-original-images-in-alertdialog-using-media-content-providers/

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
public int getCount() {
        return numberOfImages;
    }
```

with

```
public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length();
    }
```

Comment: no.i want change this code.this is not work.i want load image from sdcard.but becaese i load image by File img ... i don't know i replase imageview.setImageResource(imageID) with imageview.setImageBitmap()

Comment: @MahshidFallah search stack overflow for code for reading images from storage, if there is any error post it

Answer (score 0):

First properly explain what do want to set **Drawable** or **Bitmap**?

If `Bitmap` then this is how you should set bitmap(make a list of bitmaps and then):

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmaps[position]);
```

if `Drawable` then(make list of drawable id's)

```
imageview.setImageResource(drawables[position]);
```

This is how make bitmap list:

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmaps = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();


File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/momayezi/"+_area+"-"+_domain+"-"+_block+"-"+_melk+"-"+_build+"-"+_apar+"-"+_senfi);
    File[] files = dir.listFiles();
    numberOfImages=files.length;


    for (int i=1;i<=numberOfImages;i++)
    {

File f = new File("/sdcard/momayezi/"+_area+"-"+_domain+"-"+_block+"-"+_melk+"-"+_build+"-"+_apar+"-"+_senfi+"/pic"+i+".png");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(f.getAbsolutePath());
if(bmp!=null){
bitmaps.add(bmp);
}
}
```

Comment: Bitmap.but app have an error.and becase i run it in physical device when it have an error i don' know what's error

Comment: imageView.setImageResource(imageIDs[position]);  this is drawable code. where is your bitmap list?